# error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char [50]'

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, queue, char

Hola buen dia al que lea esto, tengo un problema con un programa que quiere insertar un elemento a una cola, el dato es `char` cadena y al momento de compilar me sale este error `error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char [50]'` y no se a ques se debe.
Si alguien puede ayudarme a resolverlo se lo agradezco de antemano.
Codigo :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Nodo
{
    char nombre[50];
    Nodo *siguiente;
};

void menu();
void pushCOla(Nodo *&, Nodo *&, char[50]);

int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    int opcion;
    Nodo *frente = nullptr, *fin = nullptr;
    char nombre[50];

    do
    {
     cout<<".:MENU:."<<endl;

     cout<<"1-Ingresar usuario"<<endl;

     cout<<endl;
     cout<<"Ingrese la opcion deseada: "; cin>>opcion;

     switch(opcion)
     {
         case 1:

            cout<<"Ingrese los datos del usuario: "<<endl;

            cout<<"Nombre :"; cin.getline(nombre, 50, '\n');

            pushCOla(frente, fin, nombre);

         break;
         case 2: break;
         case 3: break;
         case 4: break;
     }


     system("cls");
    }while(opcion!=4);



}

void pushCOla(Nodo *&frente, Nodo *&fin, char nombre[50])
{
    Nodo *nuevoNodo = new Nodo();


    nuevoNodo->nombre = nombre;

    nuevoNodo->siguiente = nullptr;

    if(frente == nullptr)
    {
        frente = nuevoNodo;
    }

    else
    {
        fin->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
    }

    fin = nuevoNodo;
}
```

Comment: Hola @Angel Roronoa, la variable tipo **char** almacena el valor de un carácter, y solo uno, por eso **char nombre[50]** no funciona.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es una copia del nombre al nombre de tu estructura: strcpy(nuevoNodo->nombre,nombre);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes asignar un arreglo de forma directa.

Necesitas hacerlo elemento por elemento. Así por ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    arreglo1[i] = arreglo2[i];
}
```

Por otro lado, el parámetro `char nombre[50]` se ve como un arreglo pero en realidad es un puntero.

Puedes comprobarlo [aquí](https://cppinsights.io/s/97999027).

De todos modos, puedes acceder a los elementos en las posiciones que quieras (siempre y cuando sean válidas) de igual forma que con un arreglo.

En definitiva, debes reemplazar `nuevoNodo->nombre = nombre;` por:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    nuevoNodo->nombre[i] = nombre[i];
}
```